# Safari/Iphone bounce effect triggering scroll down function in JavaScript code, making navigation bar disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've coded a personal website from scratch using HTML and CSS, but I wanted my navigation bar to disappear when the user scrolls down and then reappear when they scroll up (especially on a mobile device). I had to use some JavaScript to achieve this, but it's not a language I know much about. Everything works perfectly on Chrome (desktop), but due to the bounce effect that the Iphone produces, it disappears when you scroll to the top of the page.

I sort of know what I want to do to fix this, but since I have virtually no knowledge of JavaScript, I'm unable to implement it. Basically I want to make it so that the JS code that I've written only applies when the page is 0px or more. Since the Iphone allows the user to scroll higher than the page before the bounce effect comes into play, I assume we are briefly in negative displayed pixels.

To clarify, the bounce effect means when you scroll up past the top of the page and let go, the top of the page 'bounces' back to the top of the screen, triggering the scroll down function in my JS code, and therefore making the navigation bar disappear when the user is at the top of the page.

'''JavaScript

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("NavBar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("NavBar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

'''

'''HTML

```
<header id="NavBar">

  <img  src="" height="50px" alt="" class="logo" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-checkbox" class="nav-checkbox"> 

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href=""><li class="nav-home"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></li></a>
      <a href=""><li class="nav-portfolio">Portfolio</li></a>
      <a href=""><li class="nav-blog">Blog</li></a>
      <a href=""><li class="nav-about">About</li></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <label for="nav-checkbox" class="hamburger">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </label>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</header>
```

'''

'''CSS

```
header{
  background   :   var(--background)   ;
  text-align   :   center              ;
  position     :   fixed               ;
  top          :   0                   ;
  width        :   100%                ;
  height       :   50px                ;
  z-index      :   999                 ;
  transition   :   top .35s            ;
}


nav {
  background                  :   var(--background)             ;
  position                    :   absolute                      ;
  display                     :   flex                          ;
  justify-content             :   center                        ;
  width                       :   250px                         ;
  right                       :   0                             ;
  top                         :   100%                          ;
  border-bottom-left-radius   :   75px                          ;
  transform                   :   scale(1, 0)                   ;
  transform-origin            :   top                           ;
  transition                  :   transform 200ms ease-in-out   ;
}
```

'''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS does this odd thing of making the page bigger when scrolling to the top. Here is my solution to the same issue.

You need to add `||  window.pageYOffset < 50` to your if statement.

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos ||  window.pageYOffset < 50) {
    document.getElementById("NavBar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("NavBar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: Rather than "making the page bigger when scrolling", the iOS elastic bounce effect makes the `window.pageYOffset` property **negative**, and it triggers the `scroll` effect as the elastic bounce ends. 

=> On end of elastic scroll,  `prevScrollpos` is **negative**, and `currentScrollPos` is 0px (as the screen resets). Thus, the condition `(prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos)` condition is `false`, and the nav bar remains **hidden**.

Rather than add `window.pageYOffset < 50`, this would work as well:
`prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos > 0 ? currentScrollPos : prevScrollpos;`